# Gaussian Blur implementation generates weird output

Tags: go, math, image-processing, gaussianblur

I'm trying to implement a Gaussian Blur on golang `image.Image` objects. For the following image:

[image: Original image]

The output image generated is:
[image: Blurred result]

As one can see, the output image contains some unprocessed borders that corresponds to the current implementation decision to not process the edges, which leads me to think that I might have messed up on calculations somehow (what I mean is, this part of the implementation works, so I can discard off-by-one errors while iterating through image pixels). I've reviewed this code many times, but I can't find my mistake. I would really appreciate some help and considerations on the implementation, that could help me solve the problem. The code is contained below. If any edits or clarifications are necessary, please let me know!

```golang
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/draw"
    "image/jpeg"
    "math"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("dog.jpeg")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    img, err := jpeg.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    newImg := gaussianBlur(img, 3)

    out, err := os.Create("dog-blurred.jpeg")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = jpeg.Encode(out, newImg, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func applyGaussianFunction(x, y, stdDev float64) float64 {
    // eFactor := 1 / (2 * math.Pi * stdDev*stdDev);
    ePowNominator := -(x*x + y*y);
    ePowDenominator := 2 * stdDev*stdDev;

    return math.Pow(math.E, (ePowNominator/ePowDenominator));
}

func generateKernel(radius int) [][]float64 {
    size := 1 + (radius * 2);
    kernel := make([][]float64, size);
    stdDev := math.Max(float64(radius / 2), 1);

    sum := float64(0);

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        kernel[i] = make([]float64, size);
    }

    for i := -radius; i < radius + 1; i++ {
        for j := -radius; j < radius + 1; j++ {
            val := applyGaussianFunction(float64(j), float64(i), stdDev);
            kernel[i + radius][j + radius] = val;
            sum += val;
        }
    }

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < size; j++ {
            kernel[i][j] /= sum;
        }
    }

    return kernel;
}

func makeImageRGBA(src image.Image) *image.RGBA {
    b := src.Bounds().Size();
    rgba := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, b.X, b.Y));
    draw.Draw(rgba, rgba.Bounds(), src, image.Pt(0, 0), draw.Src);

    return rgba;
}

func gaussianBlur(img image.Image, radius int) image.Image {
    size := img.Bounds().Size();
    rgbaImg := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, size.X, size.Y));

    kernel := generateKernel(radius);

    for y := radius; y < size.Y - radius; y++ {
        for x := radius; x < size.X - radius; x++ {
            var nr, ng, nb, na float64 = 0, 0, 0, 0;

            for i := -radius; i < radius + 1; i++ {
                for j := -radius; j < radius + 1; j++ {
                    // NEW: Get pixels from original Image
                    pr, pg, pb, pa := img.At(x - j, y - i).RGBA();

                    nr += float64(pr) * kernel[i + radius][j + radius];
                    ng += float64(pg) * kernel[i + radius][j + radius];
                    nb += float64(pb) * kernel[i + radius][j + radius];
                    na += float64(pa) * kernel[i + radius][j + radius];
                }
            }

            // Handle overflow by using 64-bit alphapremultiplied values
            rgbaImg.Set(x, y, color.RGBA64{uint16(nr), uint16(ng), uint16(nb), uint16(na)});
        }
    }

    return rgbaImg;
}
```

**EDITS**

- I modified the code so that pixels are read from the original image, not from `rgbaImg`
- I've also commented `eFactor` from the `applyGaussianFunction` function, since I'm already normalizing the kernel with the `sum` variable
- Modified `.Set` method to use 64-bit RGBA struct

This is the newly generated image
[image: Blurred output]

Those black borders are easy to solve, I'm already working them out. This is not a part of the problem anymore.

Comment: I thought that the playground link with the code would suffice, but I guess I'll just edit it and paste the code here

Comment: MRE implies debugging effort on your part. -- numerical overflow. learn about the value range of uint8. since your borders look not-garbled, perhaps investigate how you handle borders, and why non-border pixels are getting garbled.

Comment: in `generateKernel`, you add to `sum` but never use that. why?

Comment: I forgot to paste that part, sum is used to normalize the kernel

Comment: With the regards to edge handling. I chose to not handle them, so the borders will not be processed anyways

Comment: If you're going to normalize the sum of the kernel (which is the right thing to do) then you don't need to compute `eFactor`, it's irrelevant!

Comment: I'm assuming that removing `eFactor` wont cause changes in the output right? I just removed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading from the same image that you're writing to. You shall read from the original image instead:

```
pr, pg, pb, pa := img.At(x+j, y+i).RGBA()
```

**EDIT:**
Additionally, `Image.At` returns `color.RGBA`, and `func (color.RGBA) RGBA` [returns colors in the 0 to 0xFFFF range](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color#Color). However `color.RGBA` constructor expects them to be in 0 to 255 range. You may want to use `color.RGBA64` when writing the result:

```
rgbaImg.Set(x, y, color.RGBA64{uint16(nr), uint16(ng), uint16(nb), uint16(na)});
```